# Android vibrate while button on hold

Tags: android

Help please. Here is what I am trying to achieve, I have this button that when I click it will vibrate phone on depending on how long you press the button.

like you hold the button for 5 seconds the vibrate will be 5 seconds.

just like a **throttle**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Vibrator vb = (Vibrator)   getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                while((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){ 
                            vb.vibrate(100);  
                }
            return false;
        }

    });
}
```

in my code the vibrate is like this it stops every 100 ms. also it crashes the phone

> la la la la la la la la

I want to achieve a vibrate that would be something like this. the longer you will click and hold the longer it will vibrate

> laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: pls describe what your exact problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have code there to start the vibration. You can increase the duration to something that is unrealistic for someone to hold their finger down for (10 min?).

When they lift their finger call cancel

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Vibrator vb = (Vibrator)   getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    if((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){ 
        vb.vibrate(1000*60*10);//10mins 
        return true; 
    }
    if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        vb.cancel();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: its better than use handler and in the event down use this  handler.post(runnable); and  if(count<2000)  
             {  
                 handler.postDelayed(runnable, 200);  
             }  
             //??  
             else   
             {
// call Viberate method  
             }

Comment: @ArslanAhmad I can't understand that in a comment. Perhaps you should make it into an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 import android.os.Vibrator;     
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);


 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            boolean isReleased = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL;
            boolean isPressed = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;

            if (isReleased) {
                // do whatever you want
            } else if (isPressed) {
                  v.vibrate(500);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Note:

Don't forget to include permission in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```